# Textures not showing SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to write a very simple card matching game. I have the game load with cards in a vector with a generic card back picture. Then, on mouse click release, it checks location of the click and finds a card in the vector with that location. I want the card clicked to then show another picture. Cannot seem to get the picture to show on click but the original generic card back pictures do show on the cards.

```
sf::Texture pic1;
if (card.picture == 0) {
     if (!pic1.loadFromFile("dog.jpg")) {
        // error...
        cout << "can't load dog.jpg" << endl;
    }
} else if (card.picture == 1) {
    if (!pic1.loadFromFile("cat.jpg")) {
        // error...
        cout << "can't load cat.jpg" << endl;
    }
}
```

this is how the texture is made. Then I try to apply it to the current card.

```
sf::Sprite temp;
temp.setTexture(pic1);
card.setTexture(temp); // this function just does texture = spriteTexture;
```

nothing seems to change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does pic1 go out of scope because Shapes and Sprites don't copy textures. Can you post more of the code?

Comment: @Rabster I would post the whole file but it seems to be too long.

Comment: Sent to soon, my bad.
`        Card newCard(row, column, picture); // row, column, which picture
        sf::Sprite back;
        back.setTexture(backOfCard);
        back.setPosition(x, y);
        if (x == 360) {
            x = 90;
            y = y + 125;
        }
        else {
            x = x + 90;
        }
        newCard.setTexture(back);`
This is how i set up the first texture that seemed to work.

Comment: I tried to apply that same logic but it didn't seem to work. I am not sure what code would be helpful to post.

Comment: Give us the entire class and we'll sort it out. Is this OOP or procedural? If it's procedural, give us the entire method around the code snippet which you posted andalso the method where you draw the card. Edit it in your question instead of posting it as a comment, then you can comment with @ to interested users saying that you updated the question with more code.